# Any inbuilt Javascript function to encode '?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, character-encoding

I'm looking to encode special characters(ex: Japanese chars) along with `'`.
encodeURIComponent() encodes special characters, but does not encode `'`.

Any inbuilt Javascript function which does both(i.e encode Japanese chars as well as `'`?

Comment: What kind of encoding are you looking for?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` doesn't need to encode `'`, because that's a valid character in a URI. Why would you want to encode `'`?

Comment: I want to encode *all* the special characters with a function which is char-set safe. `'` collides with some strings which already contains `'`.

Comment: I fear there's no built in function for that, so use encodeURIComponent and replace its return value yourself using regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`escape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) and [`unescape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp).

---

Update: OK, escape/unescape aren't I18N friendly.  You say `encodeURIComponent` gets you most of the way there, but misses a few chars, namely `'`.  We can make a helper function `utf8escape` that uses `encodeURIComponent` but also takes care of any remaining chars to escape, namely `'`:

```
 <html><head><title></title>
        <script>
            function utf8escape(s) {
                s = encodeURIComponent(s);
                s = s.replace(/'/, '%27');
                return s;
            }
            function enc() {
                var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
                f1.value = utf8escape(f1.value);
            }
            function dec() {
                var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
                f1.value = decodeURIComponent(f1.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="f1" name="f1" size="80"/><br/>
        <button onclick="enc()">Encode</button>
        <button onclick="dec()">Decode</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This implementation is maybe inefficient, but you get the general idea, I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately these 2 functions are not char-set safe. Not good for I18N.

Comment: I didn't quite get you @Mike.

Comment: @pavanlimo: sorry, I had a typo.  I updated my answer.  Hopefully it is relevant and helpful.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think this is an entirely uncommon problem. I was working on a project using `java.net.URLEncoder`, and we ran into a problem with its encoding spaces as `+`.  We needed spaces encoded as `%20`.  We looked at [uriEscaper](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/util/common/base/CharEscapers.java) from the Google GData library, but in this particular instance, we chose to post-process the output of `URLEncoder` rather than introduce a third party library.  It wasn't an I18N issue, of course, but similar anyhow.

Comment: Why can't we have an inbuilt function which encodes each and every character?!!!. Isn't it a simple and a usecase?

Comment: @pavanlimo I agree.  It is frustrating when something seemingly so simple (simple for the authors `encodeURIComponent`, anyway) -- and potentially useful -- is glaringly omitted.